# How to use ConnectionProvider.Builder forRemoteHost for Spring WebClient

Tags: spring-webflux, spring-webclient

I am trying to create Spring WebClient for making HTTP calls to other services.

I am using ConnectionProvider for setting the connection-related configuration for example maxConnections, maxIdleTime etc.
I need to set the custom value of maxConnections for a particular host. Is there a way to do this in Spring WebClient?

There is a method called **forRemoteHost** but I am not really clear on how to use that ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to customize `ConnectionProvider` while building `WebClient`

```
WebClient createWebClient(Map<SocketAddress, Integer> hosts) {
    ConnectionProvider.Builder builder = ConnectionProvider.builder("http");
    hosts.entrySet().forEach(entry ->
        builder.forRemoteHost(entry.getKey(), spec -> spec.maxConnections(entry.getValue()))
    );

    HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.create(builder.build());
    ClientHttpConnector connector = new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient);

    return WebClient.builder()
             .baseUrl(...)
             .clientConnector(connector)
             .build();
}
```